# NSTimer with delegate method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates, nstimer

I'm trying to set up an NSTimer on a delegate - I'm so very new to objective-c so apologies if this doesn't make much sense. But what I have written is:

```
animationTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)((1.0 / 60.0) * animationFrameInterval) target:self.delegate selector:@selector(drawView) userInfo:nil repeats:TRUE];
```

Unfortunately this just doesn't work. Can someone point me in the right direction? My mind has fried!!

Comment: Sorry the error I get in the crash report is this:
[mugalugAppDelegate drawView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Which means it can't find the method right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got it right.

Just add a colon in the method name, i.e. @selector(drawView:).  Also, by convention objective-c coders use YES and NO.

Answer (score 4):

Most likely the method signature for `drawView` is incorrect. From the NSTimer class reference:

> The message to send to target when the
>   timer fires. The selector must have
>   the following signature:
>
> `- (void)timerFireMethod:(NSTimer*)theTimer`

So, your `drawView` method should look like this:

```
- (void)drawView:(NSTimer*)theTimer
{
// Draw the view
}
```

Also, correct your code to be this (notice the colon following "drawView"):

```
animationTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)((1.0 / 60.0) * animationFrameInterval) target:self.delegate selector:@selector(drawView:) userInfo:nil repeats:TRUE];
```

On a side note, I'm not sure what your `drawView` is responsible for (I would assume drawing a view). However, there are built-in mechanisms for drawing, which should be followed (except for rare circumstances). Usually, if you have an NSView, you call `setNeedsDisplay`, which will cause the UI to tell your NSView to redraw itself by calling your NSView's `drawRect:`. I only mention this since you said you were new to Objective-C, so you might not be aware of this, and end up writing more code than you need to. If you follow this design, you could have your timer call `setNeedsDisplay` periodically.